# How to get the Azure Blob Uri from Azure Functions with Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a BlobTrigger azure function on Powershell. I am trying get the **blob uri** in order to create a managed disk out of this vhd blob with the below scipt:

```
$diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -AccountType $storageType -Location $location -CreateOption Import -StorageAccountId $storageAccountId -SourceUri $sourceVHDURI

New-AzDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $diskName
```

From the cloud shell, i can get the uri with code below:

```
$(Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob myblob -Container 'mycontainer' -Context $StorageContext).ICloudBlob.uri.AbsoluteUri
```

But with Azure Functions, i cannot. My AF code is below:

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param([byte[]] $InputBlob, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write out the blob name and size to the information log.
Write-Host "PowerShell Blob trigger function Processed blob! Uri: $($InputBlob.ICloudBlob.uri.AbsoluteUri)"
```

`$InputBlob.ICloudBlob.uri.AbsoluteUri` returns empty. I have checked [blob documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.commands.common.storage.resourcemodel.azurestorageblob?view=azurerm-ps)  , but couldn't find any solutions.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `$InputBlob` already contains the data from the blob as a byte array. Are you sure you need the URI?

Comment: I have added to the question my script which creates a NewAzDisk. There, i need the blob uri for -SourceUri parameter. I don't know how to create a NewAzDisk by using a byte array with Powershell

Comment: `$TriggerMetadata.Uri` should give you the URI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `$TriggerMetadata.Name` to get the name, or `$TriggerMetadata.Uri` as suggested by @Anatoli Beliaev.

As an alternative, you can try something like this (untested):

```
param([Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.ICloudBlob] $myBlob)
```

This works in .NET at least, and the documentation looks like it might behave similarly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#type-casting-for-triggers-and-bindings

> For certain bindings like the blob binding, you're able to specify the type of the parameter.
>
> For example, to have data from Blob storage supplied as a string, add the following type cast to my param block:
>
> ```
> param([string] $myBlob)
> ```

Comment: `[string] $myBlob` will still give you the same content of the blob, just converted to a string.

Comment: Ah, obviously it does, I somehow got confused. Thanks for the info, I changed the answer.

Comment: @AlexAIT I am using $TriggerMetaData.Name to get Name of blob but it happens to be empty. Please let me know quick fix if possible. Otherwise i'll post different thread for the same.